# C compiling error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_stringAdd"

Tags: c, macos, compiler-errors

I'm trying to build `i8086emu` which is an crossplatform emulator.

I'm under mac `
I did as the README said.

When I run `make` command after `./configure`, I got the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_stringAdd", referenced from:
      _i8086errorEx in i8086error.o
      _i8086warningEx in i8086error.o
      _i8086clearLog in i8086error.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [devices/i8086vga.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Of course I've googled for a solution. However I got no helpful answers.

It seems that I could fix this by modifying `Makefile`.

Could anyone give me a hint?

---

EDIT

i8086util.c

```
/* i8086emu
 * Copyright (C) 2004 Joerg Mueller-Hipper, Robert Dinse, Fred Brodmueller, Christian Steineck
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA
 */

/****************************************************/
/* Autor: RD                                        */
/* Version: 1.0                                     */
/*                                                  */
/* kleine Hilfsfunktionen                                 */
/*                                                  */
/****************************************************/

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "i8086proc.h"
#include "i8086util.h"
#include "i8086error.h"


/* Autor: RD */
/* Liefert length bits ab bit pos aus b. */
/* Bsp: getBitSnipped(b, 5, 3) liefert   */
/*      die bits die mit x markiert sind */
/*      Pos: 76543210                    */
/*             |->                       */
/*           00xxx000                    */
/*
unsigned char getBitSnipped(unsigned char b,unsigned char pos, unsigned char length)
{
    unsigned char result;
    result=b << (7-pos);
    result=result >> (7-(length-1));
    return result; 
}
*/

/* Verkettet s1 und s2 indem s1 um die Laenge von s2 */
/* erweitert wird. Gibt neues s1 zurueck.                        */
char *stringAdd(char *s1, ...)
{
    char *substr;
    va_list vlist; /* variable Argumentliste vorbereiten */

    va_start(vlist, s1); /* variable Liste starten */

    for(;;) 
    {
        substr=va_arg(vlist, char *); /* nächster Parameter */
        if(substr == NULL) break; /* NULL -> fertig! */
        //len=len+strlen(substr); /* neue Länge */
        //result = (char *)realloc(result, len); /* reservieren */
        //strcat(result, substr); /* Parameter anhängen */
        s1 = (char *)realloc(s1, strlen(s1)+strlen(substr)+1); /* reservieren */
        strcat(s1, substr);
    }
    va_end(vlist);

    return s1;
}   



/* Autor: RD */
/* vertauscht die oberen 8bit mit den unteren 8bit von i*/
/*
unsigned short swapbytes(unsigned short i) //vertauscht die unteren 8 Bit mit den oberen 8 Bit eines Words
{
    return (i<<8) | (i>>8);
}
*/
/*unsigned short joinBytes(unsigned char a,unsigned char b) //f?gt 2 bytes zu einem word zusammen, a high, b low
{
    unsigned short res;
    res=a;
    res=res<<8;
    res=res|b;
}
*/

/* JMH                      */
/* sleep fuer Mikrosekunden */
void delay(long microsec)
{
  struct timeval timeout;

  timeout.tv_sec = microsec / 1000000L;
  timeout.tv_usec = microsec % 1000000L;
  select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
}

/* JMH                                                                        */
/* Berechnet die Zeitdiff. zw 8086- und emu-Ausfuehrungsgeschwindigkeit       */
/* und setzt den emu gegebenenfalls in den sleep-modus bis die                */
/* Ausfuehrungsgeschwindigkeit wieder synchron sind.                          */
/* clocks   Takte die der 8086 benoetigen wuerde.                             */
/* usedTime Zeit(micSec) die der emu fuer die Funktionen der Takte benoetigte */
void cmdWait(unsigned int clocks, unsigned long usedTime)
{
  signed long procTime, waitTime;

  procTime = clocks*i8068_TPI;  /* Zeit die 8086 benoetigen wuerde*/
  waitTime = procTime-usedTime; /* Zeitdiff. zw emu und 8086 -> muss gewartet werden. */
  if (waitTime > 0)             /* emu war schneller als 8086 -> muss warten */
  {
    //usleep(waitTime);
    delay(waitTime);
  }
 }

/*copys the file src to file dest and creates file dest if it is not allready there*/
/*returns 1 if copy failed*/
/*returns 0 if copy was a success*/
int copyFile(char *src, char *dest)
{
 #define BUFFSIZE 1024
 int readblocks;
 FILE *infile,*outfile;
 void *buffer;

    infile=fopen(src,"r"); //quelldatei oeffnen
    if(infile==NULL)
            return 1;
    outfile=fopen(dest,"w"); //Zieldatei erstellen
        buffer=malloc(BUFFSIZE*sizeof(char));

    if(outfile==NULL)
       return 1;
while(!feof(infile))
{
    readblocks=fread(buffer,sizeof(char),BUFFSIZE,infile);
    fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),readblocks,outfile);
}

free(buffer);
fclose(infile);
fclose(outfile);
return 0;
}
```

Makefile.in

```
#@configure_input@
#Compileroptionen

SHELL = /bin/sh
subdirs = @subdirs@
top_srcdir = @top_srcdir@
srcdir = @srcdir@
prefix = @prefix@
exec_prefix = @exec_prefix@
bindir = @bindir@
datadir = @datadir@/@PACKAGE@
pixdir = @prefix@/share/pixmaps
examplesdir = @infodir@/@PACKAGE@/examples
infodir = @infodir@/@PACKAGE@
libdir = @libdir@/@PACKAGE@
mandir = @mandir@
sysconfdir= @sysconfdir@/@PACKAGE@
INSTALL=cp

WIN32=`if [ "$(TERM)" = "cygwin" ]; then echo "-D _WIN32"; fi;`
CFLAGS=@CFLAGS@
CGUIFLGS=`if [ "$(TERM)" = "cygwin" ]; then echo "-mwindows"; fi;`
CLIBS=`if [ "$(TERM)" != "cygwin" ]; then echo "-ldl"; fi;`
EMUOBJ=i8086proc.o i8086error.o i8086datatrans.o i8086emufuncs.o i8086arithmetic.o i8086control.o i8086logic.o i8086util.o i8086controltrans.o i8086wrapper.o i8086messages.o i8086strings.o i8086config.o disasm/*.o i8086devices.o
EMUSRC=*.c *.h disasm/*.c disasm/*.h emu.cfg rom.bin devices/*.c devices/*.h
EMUEX=../asm/*.asm
EMUINST=../configure Makefile.in ../config.guess ../install-sh ../mkinstalldirs
EMUDOCS=../NEWS ../README ../AUTHORS ../ChangeLog ../COPYING
DEVICES=devices/i8086pic.so devices/i8086pit.so devices/i8086sic.so devices/i8086beep.so devices/i8086vga.so
VERS=@vers@


all:
    if [ "@usegtk@" != "0" ]; then make i8086gui;else echo "GTK GUI is disabled - may be you lack of gtk!";fi;
    if [ @NCURSES_SYSTEM@ -eq 1 ]; then make i8086text;fi;

i8086gui: ${DEVICES} i8086gui.o i8086gui_emufuncs.o i8086gui_error.o i8086gui_util.o i8086gui_paint.o ${EMUOBJ}
    gcc ${CFLAGS} ${CGUIFLGS} -o i8086gui i8086gui.o i8086gui_emufuncs.o i8086gui_error.o i8086gui_util.o i8086gui_paint.o ${EMUOBJ} `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
i8086text: i8086text.o ${EMUOBJ} ${DEVICES}
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -o i8086text i8086text.o ${EMUOBJ} -lncurses ${CLIBS}

i8086devices: i8086text ${DEVICES}

#GUI
i8086gui.o: i8086gui.c i8086gui.h
    gcc ${CFLAGS} ${WIN32} -DPIXDIR=\"$(pixdir)\" -DVERSION_NUMBER=\"$(VERS)\" -D GTK_ENABLE_BROKEN -c i8086gui.c `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`

i8086gui_emufuncs.o: i8086gui_emufuncs.c i8086gui_emufuncs.h
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c i8086gui_emufuncs.c `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`

i8086gui_error.o: i8086gui_error.c i8086gui_error.h
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c i8086gui_error.c   `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`

i8086gui_util.o: i8086gui_util.c i8086gui_util.h
    gcc ${CFLAGS} ${WIN32} -D GTK_ENABLE_BROKEN -c i8086gui_util.c  `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`

i8086gui_paint.o: i8086gui_paint.c i8086gui_paint.h
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -DPIXDIR=\"$(pixdir)\" -DVERSION_NUMBER=\"$(VERS)\" -D GTK_ENABLE_BROKEN -c ${WIN32} i8086gui_paint.c `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`

#GUI-END

#EMU

i8086text.o: i8086text.c
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -DVERSION_NUMBER=\"$(VERS)\" -c i8086text.c

i8086proc.o: i8086proc.c i8086proc.h
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -DVERSION_NUMBER=\"$(VERS)\" -c i8086proc.c

i8086error.o: i8086error.c
    gcc ${CFLAGS} ${WIN32} -c i8086error.c

i8086datatrans.o: i8086datatrans.c
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c i8086datatrans.c

i8086emufuncs.o: i8086emufuncs.c
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c i8086emufuncs.c

i8086arithmetic.o: i8086arithmetic.c
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c i8086arithmetic.c

i8086control.o: i8086control.c
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c i8086control.c

i8086logic.o: i8086logic.c
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c i8086logic.c

i8086util.o: i8086util.c
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c i8086util.c

i8086controltrans.o: i8086controltrans.c
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c i8086controltrans.c

i8086wrapper.o: i8086wrapper.c
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c i8086wrapper.c

i8086messages.o: i8086messages.c i8086messages.h
    gcc ${CFLAGS} ${WIN32} -c  i8086messages.c

i8086strings.o: i8086strings.c i8086strings.h
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c i8086strings.c

disasm/*.o: disasm/disasm.c  disasm/insnsa.c disasm/insnsd.c disasm/regs.c disasm/regvals.c disasm/sync.c
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c disasm/disasm.c -o disasm/disasm.o
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c disasm/insnsa.c -o disasm/insnsa.o
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c disasm/insnsd.c -o disasm/insnsd.o
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c disasm/regs.c -o disasm/regs.o
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c disasm/regvals.c -o disasm/regvals.o
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c disasm/sync.c -o disasm/sync.o

i8086config.o: i8086config.c i8086config.h
    gcc ${CFLAGS} ${WIN32} -DDATADIR=\"$(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)\" -c i8086config.c

i8086devices.o: i8086devices.c i8086devices.h
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -c -DVERSION_NUMBER=\"$(VERS)\" i8086devices.c

#Devices
devices/i8086pic.so: devices/i8086pic.c devices/i8086pic.h i8086error.o i8086messages.o i8086util.o
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -shared -fPIC devices/i8086pic.c i8086error.o i8086messages.o i8086util.o -o devices/i8086pic.so

devices/i8086pit.so: devices/i8086pit.c devices/i8086pit.h i8086error.o i8086messages.o i8086util.o
    gcc ${CFLAGS} -shared -fPIC devices/i8086pit.c i8086error.o i8086messages.o i8086util.o -o devices/i8086pit.so -lpthread

devices/i8086beep.so: devices/i8086beep.c i8086error.o i8086messages.o i8086util.o
    gcc ${CFLAGS} ${WIN32} -shared -fPIC devices/i8086beep.c i8086error.o i8086messages.o i8086util.o -o devices/i8086beep.so

devices/i8086sic.so: devices/i8086sic.c i8086error.o i8086messages.o i8086util.o
    if [ "@usegtk@" != "0" ]; then gcc ${CFLAGS} ${WIN32} -shared -fPIC devices/i8086sic.c i8086error.o i8086messages.o i8086util.o -o devices/i8086sic.so `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`;fi;

devices/i8086vga.so: devices/i8086vga.c i8086error.o i8086messages.o i8086util.o
    if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then gcc ${CFLAGS} ${WIN32} -shared -fPIC devices/i8086vga.c i8086error.o i8086messages.o i8086util.o -o devices/i8086vga.so -lpthread `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`;fi;
#Devices-End



examples:
    nasm examples/clockmem.asm
    nasm examples/kitt.asm
    nasm examples/beep.asm

check:
    echo "This is not implemented right now!"

clean:
    rm -f *.o devices/*.so disasm/*.o i8086text i8086gui
cleangui:
    rm -f i8086gui*.o i8086gui

distclean: clean
    /bin/rm -f Makefile config.h config.status config.cache config.log
#@for dir in ${subdirs}; do \
# (cd $$dir && $(MAKE) distclean) \
# || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac; \
#done && test -z "$$fail"



install:all
    $(top_srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
    $(top_srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(devicesdir)
    $(top_srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(examplesdir)
    $(top_srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(pixdir)
    $(top_srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(infodir)
    $(top_srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)
    $(top_srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)
    $(top_srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)
    $(INSTALL) i8086text $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
    if [ "@usegtk@" != "0" ]; then $(INSTALL) i8086gui $(DESTDIR)$(bindir);fi;
    $(INSTALL) emu.cfg $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/emu.cfg.example
    $(INSTALL) rom.bin $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)
    $(INSTALL) core.dmp $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)
    $(INSTALL) i8086icon.png $(DESTDIR)$(pixdir)
    $(INSTALL) devices/*.so $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)
    $(INSTALL) $(EMUEX) $(DESTDIR)$(examplesdir)
    $(INSTALL) $(EMUDOCS) $(DESTDIR)$(infodir)$

uninstall:
    if [ "@usegtk@" != "0" ]; then /bin/rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/i8086gui;fi;
    -/bin/rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/i8086text
    -/bin/rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/emu.cfg.example
    -/bin/rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)/emu.log
    -/bin/rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)/rom.bin
    -/bin/rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)/core.dmp
    -/bin/rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(pixdir)/i8086icon.png
    -/bin/rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/i8086*.so
    -/bin/rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(examplesdir)/*
    -/bin/rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(infodir)/README
    -/bin/rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(infodir)/AUTHORS
    -/bin/rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(infodir)/ChangeLog
    -/bin/rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(infodir)/NEWS
    -/bin/rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(infodir)/COPYING
    -/bin/rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
    -/bin/rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(devicesdir)
    -/bin/rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(examplesdir)
    -/bin/rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(pixdir)
    -/bin/rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(infodir)
    -/bin/rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)
    -/bin/rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)
    -/bin/rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)
```

Comment: The linker cannot find the function, find out which library does `_stringAdd` function belongs to? add that library to the linker.

Comment: I'm sorry. Could you please specify a bit more? I'm quite new to building system and I always use IDE to run my projects. What does `add the library to the linker` mean?

Comment: Ok, forget about the linker now, first do you find out where the function is?

Comment: I've edited the question. Is that what I need?

Comment: The function missing is `_stringAdd`, there is an underscore in front of it.

Comment: It seems there is no method exactly named `_stringAdd` in the `/i8086emu/src/` directory. I've also searched outside of the project directory and still couldn't find it.

Comment: `stringAdd` is defined in `i8086utils.c`. Could you check that `i8086utils.c` or `i8086utils.o` is in makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Makefile.in` a mistake could have been made:

line 130-131, it's written:

```
devices/i8086vga.so: devices/i8086vga.c i8086error.o i8086messages.o
    if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then gcc ${CFLAGS} ${WIN32} -shared -fPIC devices/i8086vga.c i8086error.o i8086messages.o -o devices/i8086vga.so -lpthread `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`;fi;
```

I think that `i8086util.o` is missing. Try to replace with (i8086util.o appears in the two lines):

```
devices/i8086vga.so: devices/i8086vga.c i8086error.o i8086messages.o i8086util.o
    if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then gcc ${CFLAGS} ${WIN32} -shared -fPIC devices/i8086vga.c i8086error.o i8086messages.o i8086util.o -o devices/i8086vga.so -lpthread `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`;fi;
```

Edit

After you've done this, re-run `./configure`, then make

Comment: I've edited the question. After modifying `Makefile.in`, there's still the same error. In `i8086util.c` there is `stringAdd` method but not `_stringAdd`. Is that the point?

Comment: In fact the function named `stringAdd` will be decorated in `_stringAdd`, we talk about the same function (see [Name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)). Did you re-run the `./configure` script?

Comment: Awesome! Now it can be built successfully!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I guess you've used i8086emu. Just now I built it without error. But after that I couldn't use `i8086gui` or `i8086text` in `zsh`. How should I run it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I never used it! I just begin to learn autotools (Makefile.in) last week. Do not hesitate to open a new question.